# Conditional response with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, pjax

In my application I am using pjax to serve partial response on a page. As far as I understand pjax needs same url for partial as well as full response, for example the following url for serving the users list:

Full response:
//youwebsite/users

Partial response:
//youwebsite/users (along with X-PJAX header)

If the url is requested with X-PJAX header partial response is needed, i.e just users list whereas if there is no such header full response is needed from server i.e full page (header, body, footer etc along with users list.)

To accomplish this I have made a http handler to handle this kind of conditional response. I have made my TestHandler.ashx to do that:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="TestHandler" %>

#region Using Directives

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Web.UI;

#endregion


public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers["X-PJAX"] != null)
        {
            Type page_type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Templates/users.aspx");
            Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page_type);               
            page.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
        else
        {
            Type page_type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/users.aspx");
            Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page_type);
            page.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code return the response from Templates/users.aspx page if the X-PJAX header is present in the request. Templates/users.aspx page contains the html code for users list.
If that header is not present we need to give the full response and which is given from ~/users.aspx page.

My questions:

1. Is my approach correct to handle conditional response based on
   header. Before implementing pjax I was just having one page
   "~/users.aspx" to give full response. In order to implement pjax I
   have forwarded the request to user page to TestHandler via routing so that
   TestHandler can decide which response is needed.
2. Can we give partial
   response just from  "~/users.aspx" page without implementing
   httphandler?
3. How do you approach with with ASP.NET webforms with conditional responses?

Answer (score -1):

You can move the condition inside your razor template and choose to set the Layout of the page based on that condition.

Comment: What Razor template? What Layout? This question makes no mention of those, and specifically talks about Web Forms.